# Is there a restriction on the maximum size of post data on a web application server?

Tags: websphere, application-server

In my web application there is a form which can contain a huge amount of data (this depends on the result of a previous query). When the form reaches a certain size, the servlet cannot cope and an exception is thrown. It seems that the first attempt to fetch a request parameter causes the problem.

I have tried to reproduce the problem on my test server but do not get a problem even when the data size is greater than on the production server.

As a result, I am now wondering if there is a server setting which restricts the size of data which can be passed in a request. I can only assume that there is a difference in the way the 2 servers are configured.

The application server is Websphere 7. I have tried the application using IE9, current FF and current Chrome - all produce the same result.

The exception is

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.util.RequestUtils.parseQueryString 196
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.RequestUtils.parsePostData 356
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletRequest.parseParameters 2051
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletRequest.getParameter 1651
com.acme.Servlet.getNDC 126
com.acme.Servlet.doPost 96
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service 738
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service 831
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service 1658
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest 940
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest 503
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest 181
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest 91
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest 875
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest 1592
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready 186
com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination 453
com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest 515
com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest 306
com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete 83
com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted 165
com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback 217
com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions 161
com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed 138
com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete 204
com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop 775
com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run 905
com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run 1646
```

The code

```
protected String getNDC(HttpServletRequest request)
{
    String user = request.getHeader("iv-user");
    if (user == null)
        user = "";
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
    String sessionString = session == null ? "" : session.getId();
    String action = request.getParameter(Constant.ACTION);   <=== ERROR HERE
    if(action == null)
        action = "";
    ....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems there is a restriction - at least in Websphere App Server. Here is the response from IBM...

> I reviewed your problem description. You are right, WAS 7 has number
>   of maximum number of parameters allowed in inbound requests, but the
>   number is very high, it is 10000 in both GET and POST requests. If you
>   do not want to limit the number of parameters that can be included in
>   a request you have to set "com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.maxParamPerRequest"
>   webcontainer custom property to -1, for details see "Web container
>   custom properties" -
>   http://www14.software.ibm.com/webapp/wsbroker/redirect?version=compass&product=was-nd-dist&topic=rweb_custom_props

Answer (score 2):

POST data size may be limited by a setting in the HTTP channel configuration:

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/urun_chain_typehttp.html

If there is a Web server in front of the WAS, then you should also check the `PostSizeLimit` property in the plug-in configuration:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21460889